# Does Socket ReceiveAsync support UDP?

Tags: c#, sockets, asynchronous, udp

I have seen examples of ReceiveAsync for TCP, but not UDP.  Is ReceiveAsync compatible with UDP? If so, have you seen any examples?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

UDP is a datagram-oriented protocol, so you'd use the [Socket.ReceiveFromAsync Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.receivefromasync.aspx).

*Example:*

```
var s = new Socket(SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
s.Bind(localEP);

var e = new SocketAsyncEventArgs();
e.Completed += OnReceive;
e.RemoteEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.IPv6Any, 0);
e.SetBuffer(new byte[BufferSize], 0, BufferSize);

if (!s.ReceiveFromAsync(e)) OnReceive(s, e);
```

Comment: Shouldn't the RemoteEndPoint of e be also assigned the localEP? They would accept messages from different connections (e.g. IPAddress.IPv6Any in the SAEA and IPAddress.IPv6None in localEP) otherwise and only the most restrictive setting is applied.

Comment: @HaMster: When receiving UDP datagrams, `localEP` is the endpoint on which datagrams are received (the destination of datagrams), and `e.RemoteEndPoint` specifies the permissible endpoint(s) from which datagrams are accepted (the source of datagrams). `e.RemoteEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.IPv6Any, 0);` means that datagrams from any source are accepted; `e.RemoteEndPoint = localEP` would mean that only datagrams sent from the same endpoint are accepted.

Comment: that totally makes sense, I guess I'm thinking before writing next time^^